# cmake 2.8.12.2 AUTOUIC not working: bug or missing feature?

Tags: qt, cmake, uic

I'm building a Qt project with CMake.
With cmake-3.8.2 on macOS or Windows everything ok. On Ubuntu 14, where I have cmake-2.8.12.2, moc is run, but uic is not run.
In `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
```

and the .ui file is not specified anywhere (but has the same of a class, so I have SDFDialog.h, SDFDialog.cpp, SDFDialog.ui)

On Ubuntu 14 with cmake-2.8.12.2 this is the output:

```
$ cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target v_repExtSDF_automoc
[  4%] Automoc for target v_repExtSDF
Generating moc_SDFDialog.cpp
Generating moc_UIFunctions.cpp
Generating moc_UIProxy.cpp
[  4%] Built target v_repExtSDF_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target v_repExtSDF
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/v_repExtSDF.dir/ImportOptions.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/v_repExtSDF.dir/SDFDialog.cpp.o
/home/user/Development/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_4_0_64_Linux.rev9/programming/v_repExtSDF/SDFDialog.cpp:4:26: fatal error: ui_SDFDialog.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ui_SDFDialog.h"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/v_repExtSDF.dir/SDFDialog.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/v_repExtSDF.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

while on macOS with cmake-3.8.2 uic is correctly run:

```
$ cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target v_repExtSDF_autogen
[  4%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target v_repExtSDF
Generating MOC source v_repExtSDF_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_SDFDialog.cpp
Generating MOC source v_repExtSDF_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_UIFunctions.cpp
Generating MOC source v_repExtSDF_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_UIProxy.cpp
Generating MOC compilation v_repExtSDF_autogen/moc_compilation.cpp
Generating UIC header v_repExtSDF_autogen/include/ui_SDFDialog.h
[  4%] Built target v_repExtSDF_autogen
...
```

Is this a bug or missing feature?
In case it is a missing feature, what's the minimum required cmake version ?
Is there some workaround to make uic run also on cmake-2.8.12.2 without changing the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/fferri/v_repExtSDF/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) too much?

Comment: I don't use system qt5. I manually installed Qt and set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/qt-5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake` so all the paths are OK and manually running uic to generate the missing file works as expected.

Comment: CMAKE_AUTOUIC has been introduced with CMake 3.0 so it is not available in 2.8.12.2. If you cannot upgrade cmake on Ubuntu you can use the qt4_wrap_ui or qt5_wrap_ui macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the info given by @vre and @Antwane, I added this workaround to my CMakeLists.txt and now it supports CMake 2.8 too:

```
if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.0)
    qt5_wrap_ui(FORMS SDFDialog.ui)
    add_custom_target(uic_cmake28_compat ALL DEPENDS ${FORMS})
endif()
```

I'll eventually get rid of this workaround when Ubuntu 14.04 goes end of life.

Comment: You may use `VERSION_LESS` instead of `LESS` when comparing version numbers

Comment: thanks! it also makes sense to just use `${CMAKE_VERSION}`

Answer (score 1):

AUTOMOC feature has been introduced by CMake 2.8.6.
AUTOUIC feature has been introduced by CMake 3.0.x.

As a result, on Windows and macOS, you can use them since you have a CMake version including both features. On Ubuntu, your version 2.8.12 doesn't support AUTOUIC so you can't use it.

Source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html

Since your Ubuntu version is very old, maybe it is a good idea to upgrade to the next LTS (16.04). Or, you could try to install a more recent CMake version:

- either by using a PPA providing CMake 3 for your ubuntu 14.04. For example https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-3.x
- or by compiling it yourself: https://cmake.org/install/ In that case, you may have some issues regarding outdated dependencies.

Comment: Cmake 2.8 is really a version form the stone age.

Comment: I agree, it's a draw back of using a LTS version of Ubuntu (but not the latest)

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from adding a PPA or just downloading a newer version from cmake.org.

Comment: it is true that CMake 2.8 is ridicolously old, but that's what you get with Ubuntu 14.04, which is an LTS not at end-of-life yet. I added a workaround to that as an answer to this question